# why adding date object and a time object returns an incorrect value?

Tags: php, date

This is my code. Im adding a date object and a time object. But the answer is returning incorrect value. how can i do this otherwise?

```
$time_obj           = mktime(23, 20, 10);
$date_obj           = mktime(0, 0, 0, 07, 09, 2013);
$new_date                   = $time_obj+$date_obj;
$date_str           = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $new_date);
echo($date_str);
```

$date_str is an incorrect value. how can i overcome this?

Comment: What's expected value? What is real output?

Comment: Have you tried converting your $time_obj to a date value using same date as your $date_obj?

Comment: the mktime() function returns integer numbers, that represents seconds since 1970. so if you add this two numbers. You get something wirred. Since the linux timestamps have a limitation, it probably just starts again earlier.

Comment: If you actually worked with DateTime objects rather than simply with unix timestamps (calling them objects doesn't actually make them objects), you can add a DateTimeInterval to a DateTime object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nice solution to the problem of adding dates is to use the wonderful `DateTime` classes:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-07-09');
$time = new DateInterval('P23H20M10S');
$date->add($time);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This has the effect of separating the idea of a period (such as the time, in this case) from the absolute date. What you were doing was essentially adding two absolute dates together, with inevitably confusing results.

Answer (score 1):

The mktime() function returns integer numbers which represent seconds since 1970. So if you add these two numbers, you get something weird. Since the timestamps are stored as integers, the addition is subject to integer overflow, so for 32-bit integers you probably get a date in the past.

```
mktime(23, 20, 10) + mktime(0, 0, 0, 07, 09, 2013)
1373404810 +  1372543200 = 2'745'948'010 seconds since 1970
```

by the way, found this: As of PHP 5.1.0, this parameter became deprecated. As a result, the new timezone handling features should be used instead.

Comment: which is exactly what the OP would have figured out if he had used `echo` to troubleshoot the issue... where's @claarman? Lord of the Stack?

Answer (score 0):

Because `mktime` always returns a timestamp, which is the number of seconds from the "epoch" (which is 1970-01-01, 00:00:00 UTC).

`mktime(23, 20, 10);` does *not* return number of seconds in "23 hours, 20 minutes and 10 seconds". It returns number of seconds between the epoch and **today's date**, 23:20:10.

You can overcome this as follows:

```
...
$time_obj = 23*3600 + 20*60 + 10;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a timestamp "time only". It will always contain the date *and* the time.

Timestamps are always the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

Accordingly, `mktime()` will always return a full timestamp. The parameters you omitted in

```
mktime(23, 20, 10);
```

will automatically be substituted with the current date, so internally it will look like this:

```
mktime(23, 20, 10, 6, 7, 2013);
```